# make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/Config.pm', needed by `makefile'. Stop

Tags: windows, perl, makefile, git-bash

I'm trying to install some extra modules in the git bash perl on windows.  I got stuck trying to get `ExtUtils::ParseXS` installed.  I was able to get the C part compiled (that's the hard part), but then it stops with this error: `make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/Config.pm', needed by 'makefile'.  Stop.`

The strange thing is, that `/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/Config.pm` exists!

Here are the parts of the (generated) Makefile that's failing (full Makefile is too large for stackoverflow):

```
# This Makefile is for the ExtUtils::ParseXS extension to perl.
...
DIRFILESEP = /
DFSEP = $(DIRFILESEP)
PERL_ARCHLIBDEP = /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl
FIRST_MAKEFILE = Makefile
...
# Where is the Config information that we are using/depend on
CONFIGDEP = $(PERL_ARCHLIBDEP)$(DFSEP)Config.pm $(PERL_INCDEP)$(DFSEP)config.h
...
# We take a very conservative approach here, but it's worth it.
# We move Makefile to Makefile.old here to avoid gnu make looping.
$(FIRST_MAKEFILE) : Makefile.PL $(CONFIGDEP)
    $(NOECHO) $(ECHO) "Makefile out-of-date with respect to $?"
    $(NOECHO) $(ECHO) "Cleaning current config before rebuilding Makefile..."
    -$(NOECHO) $(RM_F) $(MAKEFILE_OLD)
    -$(NOECHO) $(MV)   $(FIRST_MAKEFILE) $(MAKEFILE_OLD)
    - $(MAKE) $(USEMAKEFILE) $(MAKEFILE_OLD) clean $(DEV_NULL)
    $(PERLRUN) Makefile.PL
    $(NOECHO) $(ECHO) "==> Your Makefile has been rebuilt. <=="
    $(NOECHO) $(ECHO) "==> Please rerun the $(MAKE) command.  <=="
    $(FALSE)
```

I'm running the make command in git bash.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check which `make` is being used.

Comment: Does it have to be MSYS ("git bash")? There's also cygwin, or better yet WSL.

Comment: $ where make
C:\GnuWin32\bin\make.exe

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Is that the directory in which "git bash" is installed? You're trying to install ExtUtils::ParseXS in a MSYS unix emulation environment, but I think you're using a Windows build of `make` instead of an MSYS build of `make`.

Comment: I'm wondering if GnuWin32 make even understands that "/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl" is a git bash path on Windows, and if not, how do I fix Makefile.PL to use Windows paths?

Comment: "make" doesn't come with git bash - I had to install it separately

Comment: Yes, but you need to install the one for the right OS. You installed a Windows build of `make`, but you're using a bash built by/for the MSYS unix emulation environment. I have no experience with MSYS, just Cygwin, and Ubuntu under WSL2

Comment: If you want to work in Windows, install a [Windows build of Perl](https://strawberryperl.com/). That will generate a `Makefile` for Windows, and use an included Windows build of `make`. (`gmake`, actually, IIRC.)  I just assumed you were using a unix emulation environment on purpose

Comment: Yes I make use of lots of shell scripts for testing Pythonizer, and I'm more comfortable using bash than Windows CMD as well.  I'm trying to add Date::Calc to Pythonizer but first I have to get it to install in my git bash perl.

Comment: I think it would be a lot easier to use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) instead of MSYS. Very same idea. It's a unix emulation environment just like MSYS. Provides bash, git, perl, make, python, whatever. It comes with a package manager with a Windows GUI interface. (Basically, the Cygwin installer itself can be used as a package manager. There's also a command-line interface if you so desire.)

Comment: Personally, I now use Ubuntu installed under [Windows Subsystem for Linux v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install). Think of it as a VM for Linux built into Windows. Relatively easy to install. (No need for partitions or anything like that.) The host can access the VM's files (through `\\WSL$`) and vice-versa (through `/mnt/c`)

Comment: I tried the ezwinports version of make with the same error - I'll try your other suggestions - thanks!

Comment: Well yeah. Still a Windows program that knows nothing of your unixy envionrment

Comment: Looks like you could also go with MSYS2, which has a package manager. But I'm not familiar with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Git bash" is a bash built using MSYS, a unix emulation environment.

You are using a Windows build of `make`, and you expect it to interact with that virtual unix environment. Only programs built using MSYS can do that.

As such, you need to figure out how to install a `make` built using MSYS.

---

Unless you have a particular reason to use the bash provided by git, I suggest using an alternative. I suspect it will be a lot easier.

It looks like MSYS2 has a package manager, and might be a lot more usable. But I know nothing about it.

You could use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). It's unix emulation environment just like MSYS. It provides bash. But not just bash. It provides git, perl, make, python, and a whole lot more through its package manager. The package manager has an easy-to-use Windows GUI interface (as well as a command-line interface). (The Cygwin installer itself is the package manager. Re-run it any time to update, remove or add packages.) I've used this for a long time, and I still do a little.

I now use [Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4MSV6) installed under [Windows Subsystem for Linux v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install). Think of WSL as a VM for Linux built into Windows. Relatively easy to install. (No need for partitions or anything like that.) The host can access the VM's files (through `\\WSL$`) and vice-versa (through `/mnt/c`), but the programs are native Linux programs; they will only run inside of the VM. A number of Linux distros are available.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm trying WSL.  It's finding issues in my Pythonizer tests running on unix that I'm fixing.  First issue is ^R characters in shebang lines are not handled here, but they were handled in git bash.

Comment: DC2 (^R)? You mean CR (^M)? Either way, the correct way to handle them is to treat them as part of the file name. If there's no ^R/^M in your file name, then you provided the wrong file name. The bug is yours.

Comment: In other words, you're using unix now, so you need to use unix text files, not Windows text files.

Comment: Yeah I meant \r not ^R

Comment: So yeah, CR. __

Comment: Quickly learning the :set ff=unix option in vi! :-)

Comment: Or fix your files using `dos2unix`. You can use `find . -type f \( -name '*.pl' -o -name '*.pm' \) -exec dos2unix {} +` to recursively fix them.

Comment: Thanks now my test for perl builtin fails because the Ubuntu perl is 5.34 not 5.36 and they don’t have 5.36 available

Comment: I use perlbrew. I can have multiple version of Perl installed. I'm not limited to what Ubuntu provides. And I don't mess anything up when I install a module.